# Writing a function to return position of node

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add a function to find node position when user enter a value(character), and return the position of the node.

I tried following the steps in delete function since it seems similar but i can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// self-referential structure                       
struct listNode {                                      
   char data; // each listNode contains a character 
   struct listNode *nextPtr; // pointer to next node
}; 

typedef struct listNode ListNode; // synonym for struct listNode


// prototypes
void insert(ListNode* *sPtr, char value);
char delete(ListNode* *sPtr, char value);
int find(ListNode* *sPtr, char value);
void printList(ListNode* currentPtr);
void menu(void);

int main(void)
{ 
   ListNode* Head = NULL; // initially there are no nodes
   char item; // char entered by user

   menu(); // display the menu
   printf("%s", "? ");
   unsigned int choice; // user's choice
   scanf("%u", &choice);

   // loop while user does not choose 3
   while (choice != 4) { 

      switch (choice) { 
         case 1:
            printf("%s", "Enter a character: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &item);
            insert(&Head, item); // insert item in list
            printList(Head);
            break;
         case 2: // delete an element
            // if list is not empty
            if (Head != NULL) { 
               printf("%s", "Enter character to be deleted: ");
               scanf("\n%c", &item);

               // if character is found, remove it
               if (delete(&Head, item)) { // remove item
                  printf("%c deleted.\n", item);
                  printList(Head);
               } 
               else {
                  printf("%c not found.\n\n", item);
               } 
            } 
            else {
               puts("List is empty.\n");
            } 
            break;
         case 3: // find node position
            // if list is not empty
            if (Head != NULL) { 
               printf("%s", "Enter character to find position: ");
               scanf("\n%c", &item);

               printf("Element %c is at index %d", item, find(&Head,item));
            } 
            else {
               puts("List is empty.\n");
            } 
            break;
         default:
            puts("Invalid choice.\n");
            menu();
            break;
      } // end switch

      printf("%s", "? ");
      scanf("%u", &choice);
   } 

   puts("End of run.");
} 

// display program instructions to user
void menu(void)
{ 
   puts("Enter your choice:\n"
      "   1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
      "   2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
      "   3 to find node position\n."
      "   4 to end.");
} 

int find(ListNode* *sPtr, char value)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (sPtr != NULL || value != (*sPtr)->data)
    {
        count++;
        *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I first add node using the insert function, eg: A -> B -> C. I expect it to return index 1 when user entered B as the value. I am getting segmentation fault core dumped whenever i run the code below..

Comment: `while (sPtr != NULL || value != (*sPtr)->data)` -->> `while (*sPtr != NULL && value != (*sPtr)->data)`

Comment: If you only have to walk the list, why pass a double pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is not correct.  For starters instead of this while loop

```
while (sPtr != NULL || value != (*sPtr)->data)
```

there should be the following loop

```
while ( *sPtr != NULL && value != (*sPtr)->data)
```

This statement

```
    *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
```

changes your list.

The function can look the following way

```
int find( ListNode **sPtr, char value )
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( *sPtr != NULL && value != (*sPtr)->data )
    {
        count++;
        sPtr = &(*sPtr)->nextPtr;
    }

    return *sPtr == NULL ? - 1 : count;
}
```

That is node positions start from 0. If a node with the given value is not found the function returns -1.

In fact as the list is not changed in the function the first parameter may be declare as a single pointer. In this case the function can look like

```
int find( ListNode *sPtr, char value )
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( sPtr != NULL && value != sPtr->data )
    {
        count++;
        sPtr = sPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    return sPtr == NULL ? - 1 : count;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i clearly didn't understand the difference of single and double pointers but i seem to get the hang of it now. i tried to change the code abit and can i write it this way?

```
int find(ListNode *sPtr, char value)
{
    ListNode* current = sPtr;
    
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL && value != current->data)
    {
        current = current->nextPtr;
        count++;
    }
    if (current->data == value)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @justforfun For starters the first parameter shall be a pointer ListNode *sPtr and after the loop current can be equal to NULL. So you may not use the expression current->data == value

Comment: it works perffectly fine now and i undserstand better now, thank you so much :))